# Add new metadata properties for DAM assets for as specific project in AEM in classic UI

Tags: configuration, aem

I'm aware that overlaying the default asset editors that is available in "/libs/dam/content/asseteditors" in crxde should work.

When I do that, the problem see is that the custom/new properties are added all the assets present in AEM instance, irrespective to the projects.

Is there a way to add custom/new properties with respect to the project in Classic UI?

[My current approach](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/how_to_edit_metadata.html#Creating%20New%20Metadata%20Property%20for%20Assets)